# Block anything from certain IP, injected from ISP when tethering from phone

Tags: firewall, iptables, ip-address

My ISP injects JavaScript files - most notabily bmi.js - and certain other unwanted additions to web requests when tethering from my phone.

It would be OK if the JavaScript was useful, but it is programmed terribly - and as a JavaScript developer, this really annoys me when the injected scripts break my own work! It looks like it annoys [some](http://jonatkinson.co.uk/http1238bmi-int-jsbmijs/) [other](http://blog.zoiah.net/?p=14) [people](http://www.badlydrawntoy.com/2009/08/07/tethering-the-iphone-my-experience-plus-o2s-secret-little-bmi-js-file/) too...

I'd like to block any activity to the IP address `1.2.3.*`. I've noticed 1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3.8 in use, or if anyone can give me any better solutions, I'd be happy to try.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I have to agree with George Edison with `That sounds like a terrible ISP.` The plot thickens ... while playing around with iptables and the like, I noticed that as soon as I blocked `1.2.3.4`, the script was simply injected from **another domain**. I blocked that, it moved on to another.

In my web browser, **I can access the script from ANY DOMAIN!** What the heck is the ISP doing here? For example, these URIs all respond with the script:

- `http://1.2.3.4/bmi-int-js/bmi.js`
- `http://1.2.3.5/bmi-int-js/bmi.js`
- `http://4.3.2.1/bmi-int-js/bmi.js`

and nauseatingly:

- `http://ScriptInjection-WhyDoYouExist.com/bmi-int-js/bmi.js`
- `http://google.com/bmi-int-js/bmi.js`
- `http://askubuntu.com/bmi-int-js/bmi.js`

*face palm*

Comment: That sounds like a **terrible** ISP.

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: Both my old Nokia E72 and new Nokia E6 did this. The ISP is Virgin Mobile (UK), and I am under the impression that it's o2's fault for implementing this feature in their data centres, which is wholesaled to Virgin.

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox NoScript add-on open Options > Advanced > ABE, USER ruleset, then add:

```
Site */bmi.js
Deny INCLUSION(SCRIPT)
```

Of course you can also use regular expressions, and combine multiple URL patterns in
the same rule.

You can find more info here: http://noscript.net/abe.

Answer (score 1):

The [page you linked to](http://www.badlydrawntoy.com/2009/08/07/tethering-the-iphone-my-experience-plus-o2s-secret-little-bmi-js-file/) in your question contains the following comment:

> I have found a solution! :D
>   On your iPhone go to Settings > General > Network > Cellular Data Network
>   Then Under “Cellular Data” change the APN to “mobile.o2.co.uk”
>   And change the Username to “bypass” (no quotes in both cases)
>   Then save the settings and restart your iPhone and the bmi.js file should no longer show up while tethering. Leaving you with full resolution browsing! The iPhone browser also appears a lot better since it was also affected by the js file.

Comment: Well, the problem might be that Greg doesn't have an iPhone... what then? :)

Comment: @jrg: I asked him (see my comment above) but I haven't heard anything back yet.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison I linked to three pages, not all of them were iphone users, not all of them were o2 users.

Answer (score 1):

aim your web browser @ 1.2.3.50 and you'll be able to turn off image compression which will remove that annoying javascript injection (worked on t-mobiles network anyway)

if that does not work, use adblock for firefox/chrome to blacklist the bmi.js file